# How can I not need to query the database every time?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

How can I not need to query the database every time?

From the bellow snapshot:

[image]

I have five tabs, name as: `云主机`,`云硬盘`,`云主机快照`,`云硬盘快照`,`安全组`:

And in the bottom of the list, there is `<<`, `<`, `>`,`>>`, and `GO` buttons that can calculate the page_num.

Then I can use the `localhost:8000/app_admin/myServers-1-1-1-1-1` analogous link to query the data.

`1-1-1-1-1` represents `云主机`,`云硬盘`,`云主机快照`,`云硬盘快照`,`安全组`'s page_num.

---

In the views.py, there are key codes:

```
def myServers(request, server_nid,disk_nid,snapshot_server_nid, snapshot_block_nid,security_group_nid, tab_nid):

    data = get_res_myserver(request, server_nid,disk_nid,snapshot_server_nid, snapshot_block_nid,security_group_nid, tab_nid)

    return render(request, 'app_admin/my-server.html',  {"data":data})  

...
def get_res_myserver(request, server_nid,disk_nid,snapshot_server_nid, snapshot_block_nid,security_group_nid, tab_nid):

    # query all the data, and paginator there
    ...
    return data
```

But, my issue is, every time I query the `localhost:8000/app_admin/myServers-x-x-x-x-x`, it will take a long time, sometimes more than 8 seconds(the time can not be shorter), its a long time for user experience.

So, Whether there is a method that I only query my data once, then paginator can be multiple times?

---

**EDIT**

this is the `get_res_myserver` method details:

```
def get_res_myserver(request, server_nid,disk_nid,snapshot_server_nid, snapshot_block_nid,security_group_nid, tab_nid):
    page_size = 5
    # 取出分页
    server_page_num = 1 if server_nid == None else server_nid
    disk_page_num = 1 if disk_nid == None else disk_nid
    ss_server_page_num = 1 if snapshot_server_nid == None else snapshot_server_nid  # server snapshot
    ss_block_page_num = 1 if snapshot_block_nid == None else snapshot_block_nid  # block snapshot
    sg_page_num = 1 if security_group_nid == None else security_group_nid  # security_group
    tab_nid_num = 1 if tab_nid == None else tab_nid

    data = {}

    # 云主机

    # conn找到虚拟机

    op_conn = OpenstackConn.OpenstackConn()
    server_op_list = list(op_conn.conn.compute.servers())

    import json

    server_app_list = app_admin_models.Instance.objects.filter(user=get_user(request))

    server_paginator = Paginator(server_op_list, page_size)

    try:
        server_op_page_list = server_paginator.page(server_page_num)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        server_op_page_list = server_paginator.page(1)
        server_page_num = 1
    except EmptyPage:
        server_op_page_list = server_paginator.page(server_paginator.num_pages)
        server_page_num = server_paginator.num_pages

    server_app_page_list = []

    server_data_list = []  # data封装op和app的server. 结构 [{"op_server":op_server_instance, "app_server":app_server_instance}]

    for server_op_page in server_op_page_list:
        for server_app in server_app_list:
            if server_app.id == server_op_page.id:
                server_app_page_list.append(server_app)
                server_data_list.append({"op_server": server_op_page, "app_server": server_app})

    # 云硬盘
    # TODO: server_disk (还没有安装)

    server_disk_list = []  # list(op_conn.conn.block_store.volumes())

    disk_paginator = Paginator(server_disk_list, page_size)
    try:
        server_disk_page_list = disk_paginator.page(disk_page_num)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        server_disk_page_list = disk_paginator.page(1)
        disk_page_num = 1
    except EmptyPage:
        server_disk_page_list = disk_paginator.page(disk_paginator.num_pages)
        disk_page_num = disk_paginator.num_pages

    # 快照

    snapshot_server_generator_ori = op_conn.conn.compute.images()

    snapshot_server_list_ori = list(snapshot_server_generator_ori)
    import copy
    snapshot_server_list_ori_cp = copy.copy(snapshot_server_list_ori)

    for snapshot_server in snapshot_server_list_ori_cp:
        if "snapshot" not in snapshot_server.name:
            snapshot_server_list_ori.remove(snapshot_server)

    snapshot_server_filtered_list = snapshot_server_list_ori

    snapshot_server_paginator = Paginator(snapshot_server_filtered_list, page_size)

    try:
        snapshot_server_page_list = snapshot_server_paginator.page(ss_server_page_num)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        snapshot_server_page_list = snapshot_server_paginator.page(1)
        ss_server_page_num = 1
    except EmptyPage:
        snapshot_server_page_list = snapshot_server_paginator.page(snapshot_server_paginator.num_pages)
        ss_server_page_num = snapshot_server_paginator.num_pages

    # TODO:  (云主机的块存储快照功能SDK还没有实现)
    snapshot_block_list = []  # list(op_conn.conn.block_store.snapshots())

    block_paginator = Paginator(snapshot_block_list, page_size)
    try:
        snapshot_block_page_list = block_paginator.page(disk_page_num)  # 块存储
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        snapshot_block_page_list = block_paginator.page(1)
        ss_block_page_num = 1
    except EmptyPage:
        snapshot_block_page_list = block_paginator.page(block_paginator.num_pages)
        ss_block_page_num = block_paginator.num_pages

    # 安全组
    security_groups_list = list(op_conn.conn.network.security_groups())

    security_groups_paginator = Paginator(security_groups_list, page_size)
    try:
        security_groups_page_list = security_groups_paginator.page(disk_page_num)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        security_groups_page_list = security_groups_paginator.page(1)
        sg_page_num = 1
    except EmptyPage:
        security_groups_page_list = security_groups_paginator.page(security_groups_paginator.num_pages)
        sg_page_num = security_groups_paginator.num_pages

    data['server_data_list'] = server_data_list  # VM
    data['server_disk_list'] = server_disk_page_list  # 云硬盘
    data['snapshot_server_list'] = snapshot_server_page_list  # VM的快照 (所有VM的快照)
    data['snapshot_block_list'] = snapshot_block_page_list  # 块存储的快照
    data['security_groups_list'] = security_groups_page_list  # 安全组
    data['settings_data'] = settings.OPENSTACK_USER_NETWORK
    data['tab_nid'] = tab_nid_num  # 这个是选中的哪个tab
    data['server_page_num'] = server_page_num
    data['disk_page_num'] = disk_page_num
    data['ss_server_page_num'] = ss_server_page_num
    data['ss_block_page_num'] = ss_block_page_num
    data['sg_page_num'] = sg_page_num  # 安全组

    print ("myserver_data", data)

    return data
```

---

**EDIT-2**

This is my op_conn get, and this is a singleton:

op_conn = OpenstackConn.OpenstackConn()

Comment: The database is working fine??. How long does the sql take?

Comment: Caching is always an option... although - is your query and pagination correct (it'd help if you showed that) - make sure you're not doing something like selecting a million rows from the DB into memory, then just returning the first 100, then doing the same to get the next 100 etc...

Comment: Do you follow relations to display the data in the table. You might gain sth by including some `select_related` or `prefetch_related` clauses.

Comment: @JoséRicardoPla Sometimes more than 10 seconds.

Comment: @JonClements Off course, at most 500 rows data. Can you introduce me  a more detail cache? which cache is fit my scenario.

Comment: @244boy you say "Off course" - but since you don't share the code we can't check you're not doing anything silly that could possibly cause a lot more work than required. In regards to caching, a search for "django caching" will produce a lot of results that you can then deem whether they're fit for your scenario as you haven't shared what that scenario is either...

Comment: @JonClements I have edited my post.

Comment: How much time does opening your connection and making it a list take? As you're always going to be pulling the *whole* data unless whatever `op_conn.conn.compute.servers()` is, returns something queryset like or something that can support pagination without retrieving all data first.